# UWP HighContrastScheme check in localized environment

Tags: uwp, high-contrast

AccessibilitySettings.HighContrastScheme returns localized High Contrast name
so
how  to compare string for the property like below

```
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.AccessibilitySettings accessibilitySettings = new Windows.UI.ViewManagement.AccessibilitySettings();

if(accessibilitySettings.HighContrastScheme == "High Contrast Black") // works for English but doesn't work for Korean or others languages
{
  /// some action
}
```

Comment: Instead of comparing the name, just check whether the default background color is white (or mostly white) or black (or mostly black).

Comment: this logic wont work , because Background color is changeable by user

Comment: Have you verified that the string "High Contrast Black" really is translated? I'm under the impression that it the string is always in English (although displayed to the user in their preferred language).